# Doctrine Event Subscriber causes integration tests to fail with 'There is already an active transaction' message

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, phpunit

I have an event subscriber that looks like the following:

```
class MySubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

    public function __construct(
        private MyService $service,) {
    }

    public function getSubscribedEvents(): array {
        return [
            Events::postUpdate,
            Events::postPersist
        ];
    }
}
```

Without this event subscriber class, my tests are running fine, but with this enabled, they are not even running. Before the tests, I'm creating the database schema, loading fixtures and clearing cache, all which work fine and upon test execution, I get the error listed below.

It's a very strange issue as it does not come up during local [PHPUnit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPUnit) testing, but in my [CI/CD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration#Deploy_an_artefact_from_CI) pipeline it fails with the following message:

```
PHPUnit 9.6.5 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
There is already an active transaction
```

One possible cause is the DAMA doctrine test bundle, but I have not been able to figure out how to debug it.

#### File *phpunit.xml.dist*

```xml
....
  <extensions>
    <extension class="DAMA\DoctrineTestBundle\PHPUnit\PHPUnitExtension"/>
  </extensions>
```

How can I fix this?

I am running PHP integration tests using PHPUnit in CI/CD pipelines using containers. This event subscriber class is the issue somehow, and without it, everything works fine.

Comment: I have the same problem. I am in the middle of upgrading to Symfony 6.0 and run into the same error. I have 3 Events in my project which previously worked fine with the Dama Bundle. Since the upgrade I have problems. 
Did you find a solution? I still use phpunit 8.2.9

Comment: The error message went away in my case after all other Tests were passing.